# Programming Android App using Ceylon

Tags: android, ceylon

Can I create android app using Ceylon? Since Ceylon can run of any JVM, the implementation of Ceylon to create android app should be pretty simple as far as I understand. Is it like Scala where the size of App becomes considerably larger and have to use proguard or SBT-android plugin? How viable is it?  Can Ceylon be good option for this? If yes, can somebody point me to the proper direction?

Comment: ["Ceylon inherits most of Java's syntax"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceylon_Project). How do you think that this helps you "program in Android without using Java"?

Comment: You are right. I had forgotten to look into that. My primary motivation lies in learning a language to create Android App without learning Java. Being used to python, I have really bad feelings about Java. I want to embark on one more new language to learn to program in Android which is not Java.

Comment: Odd, why, knowing Python, would you choose Ceylon over Scala?

Comment: @virtualeyes:Just hoping that the app size will be minimal which is not even achieved (as far as I have heard) using proguard or SBT-android plug-in in Scala. Otherwise, Scala seemed to be much more better choice than Ceylon.

Comment: ah right, did not catch that, mobile device concerns. There are many Java alternatives, there's gotta be something out there with a small footprint, but appealing as language (only glanced at Ceylon, Scala, Kotlin, Groovy, etc. all appeal more...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Chochos' answer is a bit outdated. [Here you can see](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ceylon-dev/BNqosBRDuSI/WuqUWfxraQcJ) that the Ceylon team has already published (January 2014) some initial Android support, even with an Eclipse plugin.

Another older thread that talks about this is [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ceylon-dev/n2ZfmaW-I2M/GhZVEa_uV44J). It would be great if during these 7 months of 2014 they have ironed out most of the kinks, and writing Android apps with Ceylon is already a pleasure. I myself will test this ASAP.

**UPDATE**: There's a ["Ceylon-Android" compatibility plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ceylon-dev/BNqosBRDuSI) that one can install.

Comment: That's why I specifically mentioned "for the remaining of 2012". I dated my answer precisely to avoid it being outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Writing Android apps in Ceylon is a long-term goal, not a priority at the moment. So at least for the remaining of 2012 I think the answer will be No, you can't write an Android app in Ceylon.

Comment: An alternative to investigate is Scala. It supports Android, seems to have the same improvements as Ceylon, and is apparently sort of difficult to learn.

Comment: Another alternative would be Kotlin. Here is a full RSS reader for Android written in Kotlin:  https://github.com/dodyg/AndroidRivers